# need assistance in simple c++ code

Tags: c++, arrays

Hey guys im trying to write a c++ code to check the number of set bits in an array of numbers.

for example first i ask how many numbers i want and then i store those numbers in an array then i loop through each number in the array and convert them to binary.
if all the bits are set for a number i need to print YES and if not then NO.
eg 7 is 111 hence all bits are set so i will print YES.

but i get a compile error which is: 'x' was not declared in this scope and expected , or ; before {  both the errors are in line 9 which is this  '`int checkbit(x){`' here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int b[20],c[50];

int checkbit(x){
    int z, i=0;
    while(x>1){
        if(x==1)
        c[i]==x;
        z=x%2;
        x=x/2;
        c[i]=z;
        ++i;
    }
    while(i>=0){
        z= c[i];
        if(z==0)
        return -1;
        --i;
    }
    return 0;   
}

int main(void){
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter the quantity of numbers you want";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Now Enter all the numbers you want";
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    cin>>b[i];
    cout<<"Checking for set bits please wait";
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        if(checkbit(b[i])==-1)
        cout<<"NO";
        cout<<"YES";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please tell me what is going on and is my code correct

Comment: Just to clarify, is this line 9 `x=x/2;`? Also, what is the purpose of this `if(x==1) c[i]==x;`do you wan to compare the values or assign them?

Comment: line no 9 is this "int checkbit(x){"  and as for if(x==1) c[i]==x;  i want to break the while when x reaches 1 because aside from the modulus i am also dividing x by 2 so when x reaches 1 at the end i want to store that one in the array and break the while loop

Comment: Well, in that case @Mikael-faust as others have mentioned below it should be `int checkbit(int x){`. The first `int` being the return type of the method and the second `int` being the type of the parameter passed in.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters in a function signature are also supposed to have their types in front of them.

So, this:

`int checkbit(x)`

should actually be:

`int checkbit(int x)`

Unless you do this, the compiler cannot find the declaration of `x` in the scope of `checkbit`, and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a type declaration for your function parameter. You have a type declaration on the return but not on the parameter.

Line 9 should read:

int checkbit(int x){

That will fix your compile error.

Comment: yes exactly i cant beleive i made such a stupid mistake thanks a lot guysss!!!! for replying so fast